# How to start an X session on RPi via ssh

Tags: ssh, xorg

I have configured Synergy to control my RPi, which I have connected to my TV.  But since the keyboard is remote and Synergy hasn't started when I boot my RPi, I've got a "chicken and the egg" problem.  How do I start X to let Synergy connect to my keyboard--before it has access to my keyboard.  (I don't want to set X to start automatically.)

Is there a way to start an X session on the RPi via ssh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't realize it would be so simple: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52887/72132

I just ssh to my RPi and run `startx&`.  My Synergy client is set to autostart with LXDE, so once I have X running I'm able to control my RPi with my remote keyboard.

Comment: This is not working, you have to run that command with sudo permissions, so
"sudo startx&".